# How to open terminal NOT as a root

Tags: 14.04, command-line, permissions

I was changing permissions of some folders in `opt` directory in Ubuntu 16. Now the problem is that terminal always opens in root mode. Is it possible to change it back to the user mode in order to avoid running `sudo -su user` each time I open the terminal?

Inside `opt` directory I have now the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 root   root   4096 jul 30 14:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root   4096 jul 27 10:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 tomcat tomcat 4096 jul 30 14:30 apache-tomcat-7.0.79
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 feb 21 11:55 atom
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root   4096 ago 24  2016 dell
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 nov 18  2016 forticlient-sslvpn
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 jul  6 17:59 google
drwxr-xr-x 30 root   root   4096 dic 24  2016 lampp
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 nov 17  2016 mssql
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 feb  8 11:06 skypeforlinux
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 jul 18  2016 sublime_text
```

Comment: well... don't change around permissions of system directories. If your home is on a seperate partition it would be the easiest just to reinstall.

Comment: Please edit the question to tell us which folders you have modified, and we can check what permissions we have for our corresponding folders. After that we can try to help you.

Comment: @sudodus: Please check my update.

Comment: I think you need help from somebody who is running Ubuntu Server. (I haven't got those directories.) -- But I must also ask if you are sure, that this is the reason why terminal is opening as root. Maybe you have changed something else somewhere else.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Server and I do not have these Directories. Only thing in /opt is Google Chrome.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff, please tell us the permissions and ownership of the Google Chrome directory/files. It may help the OP.

Comment: crafters@crafters:/opt$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 20 19:39 .
crafters@crafters:/opt$

Comment: It looks the same as the permissions of the OP. So I suspect that the terminal is affected by something else.

Comment: I think the Op is logging into the server as root so everything will be root.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/usermod-command-examples/

Comment: The permissions in /opt/ have nothing to do with a terminal session opening in root. Besides that: /opt/ does never need permissions changed. The software you install there is from tarballs and those come with them pre-set as they should be. And to all above: /opt/ is for 3rd party software so generally is empty.